# How to reduce the border size of terminal

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

[image]

I am using `screen` to split terminal.But am not able to reduce the border size.

Comment: If you are talking about the blue borders - they are drawn with pseudo graphics which means that they are actually just rectangular symbols, not lines. The only way you can make them thinner is to reduce the font size. Or you can split terminal itself, but you will lose `screen`'s features.

Comment: how can i split terminal ? losing the `screen` features won't be a problem

Comment: I'm sorry, looks like `gnome-terminal` doesn't support that feature while `konsole` and `yakuake` (from KDE) and `xfce4-terminal` (from Xfce) do support. Both of them wouldn't look perfect in gnome, but you still can give them a try.

Comment: Oh, there gnome terminal with splitting functionality exists, it's called `terminator` but I've never used it: https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html

Comment: yeah `terminator` works fine. Thanks